# Show content of secure variables in travis

Tags: travis-ci

According to this question, you need to ssh to the debug build to see the content of secure variables in travis:

[How I can decrypt secure env variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31519546/how-i-can-decrypt-secure-env-variables)

I would like to avoid to ssh to the debug build, since I have a public repo and the "ssh to debug build" option is only available for private repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple way to send me the content of these variables without revealing them to the build result.

I added one line to `before_install`:

```
- curl https://example.com/travis/$encrypted_c..._key/$encrypted_c..._iv
```

Of course I use a server where I can read the webserver logs instead of "example.com".

I found the content of the secure vars in the web server log:

```
localhost:443 52.45.185.117 - - [26/Jul/2017:13:26:21 +0200] 
    "GET /travis/cc..../a776... HTTP/1.1" 403 3652 "-" 
    "curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 
    OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3"
```

I could have added this, but this would reveal the content to the public:

```
echo $encrypted_c096724ab55d_key
```